# How do I clean up my React Native/Expo application to work with Jest?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

I have an existing project that uses React Native and Expo. Currently, the application runs fine. I'm trying to integrate Jest into the project. A basic "true=true" test in jest passes and runs without error. When I try to run any code using ES6 terms, however, the following error occurs:

```
 FAIL  screens/__tests__/home.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /Users/user/Documents/GitHub/ReadingRainbow/node_modules/react-native/index.js:13
    import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import React from 'react';
    > 2 | import { Image, View, Text, Button, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
        | ^
      3 | import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global';
      4 | import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
      5 | 

      at Runtime._execModule (node_modules/jest-expo/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1157:58)
      at Object.<anonymous> (screens/home.js:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (screens/__tests__/home.test.js:2:1)
```

I have also set up a clean, brand new project (following [these](https://docs.expo.io/) directions first and [these](https://docs.expo.io/guides/testing-with-jest/) second) to test the compare the dependencies and such against my current project. The clean project runs as intended, including import/export statements. How do I correct and clean up my real project so that jest runs without error?

I have tried deleting the node_modules folder and running npm install to reestablish the dependencies. I have also tried adjusting the preset configurations for jest, the transformIgnorePatterns, and the preset defined in babel.config.js. The most helpful explanation I've been given so far is, "[this is probably not working because] node can't use imports (without transpiling) and jest is trying to render using node instead of a browser." Any help is sincerely appreciated! Please let me know if you need further information or clarification.

Example file:

```
// Intro.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  instructions: {
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    margin: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default class Intro extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          This is a React Native snapshot test.
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Example test:

```
// __tests__/Intro-test.js
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Intro from './Intro';

test('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<Intro />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

package.json of "clean" project

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "jest-expo": "^39.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
    ]
  },
  "private": true
}
```

package.json of my actual project

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:update": "jest --verbose --coverage --updateSnapshot",
    "test:watch": "jest --verbose --watch",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.11.1",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-testing-library": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.2",
    "jest": "^26.6.2",
    "jest-expo": "^39.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
    ]
  },
  "private": true
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

jest.config.json (non-existent in "clean" project)

```
{
  "testRegex": "((\\.|/*.)(test))\\.js?$"
}
```

Comment: transformIgnorePatterns is an option that affects this. You overrode this config. package.json Jest config and jest.config.js don't sum up.

Answer (score 0):

In your `__tests__/Intro-test.js` file, just above the test, mock your component like this
`jest.mock('./Intro', () => './Intro');`

The content of your file will look like this:

```
// __tests__/Intro-test.js
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Intro from './Intro';

jest.mock('./Intro', () => './Intro');

test('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<Intro />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I was facing the exact same problem. Mocking my components solved the issue. I hope it will help you too.